# NIC statistics explanation (ethtool -S eth1)

Tags: networking, statistics

What is the meaning of each of the results from `ethtool -S eth1` command?
For example, when I used `ethtool -S eth1`, I got something like this:

```
>root@localhost ~]# ethtool –S eth1

>NIC statistics:
tx_packets: 2654
rx_packets: 3960
tx_errors: 0
rx_errors: 316
rx_missed: 0
align_errors: 9194
tx_single_collisions: 0
tx_multi_collisions: 0
unicast: 3396
broadcast: 198
multicast: 366
tx_aborted: 0
tx_underrun: 0
```

Is it correct that tx_packets, rx_packets - are transmitted and received packets? But what with the rest of the results?

Comment: Use four space indentation with code blocks, backquotes for inline code. "Could somone explain me..." is not a good question as "Yes" or "No" are the only correct answers and they won't help you much. Be so polite to read at least the two minute [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), especially the part about no distractions and no chit-chat (so definately leave out greetings from a post here).

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> tx_packets:           Trasmitted packets
> rx_packets:           Received packets
> tx_errors:            Trasmission errors
> rx_errors:            Received errors
> rx_missed:            Recieved misses
> align_errors:         Received alignment errors
> tx_single_collisions: Trasmitted singular collisions
> tx_multi_collisions:  Trasmitted multiple collisions
> unicast:              Received unicast
> broadcast:            Received broadcast
> multicast:            Recieved multicast
> tx_aborted:           Aborted trasmissions
> tx_underrun:          Aborted underruns
> ```

For a better understanding of the terminology, see [this message](https://www.mail-archive.com/cisco@groupstudy.com/msg70531.html):

> An underrun error on an ethernet is a transmission error. The way most ethernet chips transmit packets is that they DMA packet data from memory into their internal transmit fifo for sending. They do not ususally load the entire packet into the fifo before transmitting (some may have fifos smaller than the max. pkt size),
> so they go grab the data as they need it - there is usually a low-water mark in the fifo which triggers this.
>
> A transmit fifo underrun will occur if the ethernet chip cannot obtain the local bus in order to get more packet data for the fifo, and the fifo becomes empty
> before the end of the packet has been reached.

So:

- multicast - imagine trying to communicate from one system to a select number of others
- broadcast - imagine trying to communicate from one system to all other systems
- collision - imagine what will happen when two system are trying to communicate with one another simultaneously they end up blocking one another
- alignment - imagine you can only communicate in specific units. Words of 4 characters at a time only. If there is a mis-alignment of characters systems can't communicate with one another. It's the same here.

If you're interested, it may be worth taking a look at the following.

- [Ethernet Error Descriptions](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026121041/http://www.networkcomputing.com/netdesign/t15errors.html)
- [`ethtool.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5d0c230f1de8c7515b6567d9afba1f196fb4e2f4/drivers/net/ethernet/sfc/ethtool.c)

Comment: Links broken :(